# .text() returns object Object

Tags: jquery, function, text, input

So I've created a simple shopping list / to-do app. It's nearly complete, except for one nagging problem: `.text()` keeps returning `[object Object]` instead of the input captured.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. To show what I'm talking about, I included my JS script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     addItem();
     deleteAction();
     doneAction();
 });

 function addItem() {

     $("button").click(function() {
     var value = $(".input-form").val();       
         $("ul").append('<li> <span class=\"item-name\">'+value+'</span><span class=\"done\"> done</span><span class=\"delete\"> delete</span></li>');
         $(".input-form").val('');
     });
 }

 function deleteAction() {
     $(".ul-list").on("click", ".delete", function() {
      //   alert("Delete event fired.");
         $(this).closest("li").remove();
     });
 }

 function doneAction() {
     $(".ul-list").on("click", ".done", function() {
      //   alert("Done event fired.")
         $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("strike");
     });
 }
```

Here's my full code on CodePen: http://codepen.io/barackobama/pen/qOrKBp

Comment: added code from link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.name` not appear defined , appended to `DOM` when `.text()` called at `$(".name").text(value)` within string argument to .`append()` ?

Try setting `value` within string argument to `.append()` using `+` operator e.g, `<span class=\"name\">'+value` ; moving `value` variable declaration within `click` event for it to be defined, set at event ; `js` at initial codepen set `value` when `addItem()` initially called at `.ready()` , when no value yet set by user

```
 function addItem() {         
     $("button").click(function() {
         var value = $(".input-form").val();
         $("ul").append('<li> <span class=\"name\">'+value
           +'</span><span class=\"done\"> done</span>'
           +'<span class=\"delete\"> delete</span></li>');
         $(".input-form").val('');
     });
 }
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpBBX

Comment: @J.Bauer Can describe _"It didn't work."_  ? See updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpBBX , try typing "abc" at "Add Item Here" , clicking "Add New List Item"

Answer (score 0):

An answer taking into account you might want to use more than one form-entry parsing the whole formcontent into a key-value-pair-list for easy access onto it.

```
function addItem() {
     $("button").click(function() {
         var data = $('.input-form').serializeArray().reduce(function(obj,item) {                
                obj[item.name] = item.value;
                return obj;
              }, {});
         $("ul").append('<li> <span class=\"name\"></span>'+data['additem']+
                    '<span class=\"done\"> done</span><span class=\"delete\"> delete</span></li>');
         $(".input-form").val('');
     });
}
```